# Possible MacOS Catalina boost install-name bug?

Tags: c++, macos, boost, macos-catalina

I encountered some issues when trying to link boost build on MacOS Catalina. I did specifically set the include and libdir. Inspecting the install-name with `otool -l` I found, that the install-name was still set to the realative path of the binary bin.v2/libs/serialization/build/gcc-9.2/release/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/libboost_serialization.dylib.

In order to achieve the expected behaviour (and the behaviour in MacOS Mojave) I simply set the install-name by hand.

```
for name in libboost_*.dylib; do install_name_tool -id path/boost/lib/${name} ${name}; done
```

Did I miss something ? Is there an option I could have enabled ? Where there general changes to install-name in MacOS Catalina ?

Comment: Found this because I am experiencing the same issue with versions 1.55 and 1.72 on macOS Mojave.

Comment: You should submit a bug report to the Boost devs. (Submitted as an Answer because SO doesn't allow me to make comments.)